# What about restrict passwords reception to bcrypt format?

Tags: security, hash, passwords, backend

I'm learning about web security, hashing and encryption stuff.

I'm building an authentication feature for an API REST backend app. I had an idea and i wanted to know your opinion.

What if we apply data validations on "clear" password that we are supposed to recieve from the client ?

From a backend perspective, accepting only password data in a bcrypt hash form. The password would have to be hashed by the front app, sended to the backend, hashed again to compare with the password in DB.

[Scheme picture :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2vLG.png)

It could really increase the bruteforce load and time consumption and the clear/real user passwords would never go out from the user RAM.

I think it could be a good idea but i don't have enough knowledges to apply it blindlessly.

Comment: What problem does this solve? Hashing the password on the frontend doesn't really do anything if you also hash it in the backend. In the end, the data given to the backend is treated exactly the same. "*the clear/real user passwords would never go out from the user RAM.*" and? Are you trying to protect from somebody hijacking the HTTPS communication to your server? Because if somebody does that *they can already read the password*. Well, not the clear text password but they can just make a payload and paste the hash they stole. Doesn't matter in the end.

Comment: I think it could slow brute forces attacks and protect the user if its password is stole if he use the same password across multiple websites.
I think the cost of this protecion is low enough and simple to be considered.

Comment: OK, so who is stealing the data? Are they intercepting the HTTPS traffic? In which case *you have bigger problems*. Have they taken control over the user's machine? Then that's the biggest problem. The attacker can be assumed to have complete control and be able to intercept the password before it is encrypted. Again, what are you trying to solve here? It feels like you don't trust the security of HTTPS but maybe you are trying to protect the user from being compromised. In both cases it doesn't really seem to help much. If it's the HTTPS - then why don't you trust it?

Comment: That's not about trusting or not trustring anybody. That's just about adding security layers that secure at least one scenario and does not really increase the complexity. Is it not what security is about? Think about the more and the deepest scenarios possible and find solution to secure them without adding complexity or bottlenecks? I'm junior, correct me if i'm wrong but i don't think the way i feel it is bad for this case.

Comment: Which scenario is prevented, in this case? Which *plausible* real world problem is avoided?

Comment: While possible, this would considerably complicate your login process. The user would have to send the username to the server and receive the salt stored in the DB from the server. Then hash the password and send it to the server. But then you also have to make sure this process does not leak which usernames are valid...

Comment: "*and does not really increase the complexity.*" except it does. You now have to transmit the salt to the client. Which means you're exposing data. Of course, unless you omit salting, in which case...well, you just have a password, you've added no actual extra security on top of it, since the level of entropy is the same whether you hash or not. You're just artificially making a more complex password which doesn't really do anything against a pre-computed list with common passwords.

Comment: Ok! Now i'm convinced that's a shitty design but I know why now. Nice. Maybe thank you haha. My passwords are salted. Good day